# Consolidate JSON objects from CSV

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I need to consolidate an array containing JSON objects that were retrieved from a CSV file.

CSV file:

```
sector,subsector,codigo
sector1,subsector1,001
sector1,subsector2,002 
sector2,subsector1,003 
sector3,subsector1,004
sector3,subsector3,005
```

This is my code:

```
const csvtojson = function(){
    let pathToCsv = './dummy-sectores.csv'
    csv({
        colParser:{
            "sector.subsector":{
                flat: true,
                cellParser: "subsector"
            }
        }
    })
    .fromFile(pathToCsv)
    .then((json) => {
        const n = {}
        json.forEach((a)=>{
            n.sector = a.sector
            n.subsector = a.subsector
        })
        console.log(n)
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e))
}
```

What I get:

```
[ { codigo: '001',
    sector: 'sector 1',
    subsector: 'sector 1 subsector 1' },
  { codigo: '002',
    sector: 'sector 1',
    subsector: 'sector 1 subsector 2' },
  { codigo: '003',
    sector: 'sector 2',
    subsector: 'sector 2 subsector 1' },
  { codigo: '004',
    sector: 'sector 3',
    subsector: 'sector 3 subsector 1' },
  { codigo: '005',
    sector: 'sector 3',
    subsector: 'sector 3 subsector 2' } ]
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
{
 "sector1":
    [{"subsector": "subsector1", "codigo": 1},
      {"subsector": "subsector2", "codigo": 2}],
  "sector2":
    [{"subsector": "subsector1", "codigo": 3}],
  "sector3":
    [{"subsector": "subsector1", "codigo": 4},
      {"subsector": "subsector2", "codigo": 5}]
}
```

Whenever I try to use map or forEach function it just messes up everything.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy - suppose you use this [Keyang / node-csvtojson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/blob/master/readme.md)

My raw JSON parsed from your CSV placed to string looks like:

```
[{ "sector": "sector1", "subsector": "subsector1", "codigo": "001" },
{ "sector": "sector1", "subsector": "subsector2", "codigo": "002" },
{ "sector": "sector2", "subsector": "subsector1", "codigo": "003" },
{ "sector": "sector3", "subsector": "subsector1", "codigo": "004" },
{ "sector": "sector3", "subsector": "subsector3", "codigo": "005" }]
```

Formatting is not exactly same, but looks almost like JSON you wanted(?)

```
{"sector1":
[{"subsector":"subsector1","codigo":1},
{"subsector":"subsector2","codigo":2}],
"sector2":
[{"subsector":"subsector1","codigo":3}],
"sector3":
[{"subsector":"subsector1","codigo":4},
{"subsector":"subsector3","codigo":5}]}
```

```js
const csvtojson = function() {
  let CSV = 'sector,subsector,codigo\nsector1,subsector1,001\nsector1,subsector2,002\nsector2,subsector1,003\nsector3,subsector1,004\nsector3,subsector3,005';
  csv({
      colParser: {
        "sector.subsector": {
          flat: true,
          cellParser: "subsector"
        }
      }
    })
    .fromString(CSV)
    .then((json) => {
      const n = {}
      json.forEach((a) => {
        n[a.sector] = n[a.sector] || [];
        n[a.sector].push(a);
        delete a.sector;
        a.codigo = parseInt(a.codigo);
      })
      console.log(JSON.stringify(
        n
      ).replace(/:\[/g, ':\n[').replace(/([^"]),([\{"])/g, '$1,\n$2'))
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e))
}
csvtojson();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/d41f44aa/browser/csvtojson.min.js"></script>
```